# Функция для шифрования ссылок (обратимое)

Tags: php, алгоритм, шифрование

Требуется быстрая функция способная замаскировать ссылку и при передаче в замаскированном виде разобрать ее.
Входящая строка: `/?id=12&link=http://example.com/?id=123&p=param`
Исходящая: `набор символов для передачи в адресной строке`
В ссылке будет передаваться позиция рекламного объявления для определения конверсии, если ее не зашифровать, показатели могут подвергаться искажению. Любое обратимое шифрование с расшифровкой по ключу известному только мне или что-то подобное.

Comment: base64_encode / base64_decode + mcrypt_encrypt / mcrypt_decrypt Если надо что бы не кто не проичёл.

Comment: @E_p будьте добры пример для mcrypt_encrypt, возможно. обойдется этим.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например гаммирование, c простенькой гаммой и ограничением на допустимые символы:

```
<?php
function randucode($txt)
{
 $x=56780; $out="";
 for($i=0;$i<strlen($txt);$i++)
  {
   $x=((($x*65539)+0) ^ 0x7FFFFFFF) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
   $r=($x ^ ($x >> 16))& 0x3F;
   $s=ord($txt[$i]);
   if($s>=46 && $s<=127)
    {
     $s=($s ^ $r);
     if($s<46 or $s>=127) $s=($s ^ $r);
    }
   $out.=chr($s);
  }
 return $out;
}
function encode($txt)
{
 return str_replace(array("?","&","/","="),array("(",")","*",","),randucode($txt));
}
function decode($txt)
{
 return randucode(str_replace(array("(",")","*",","),array("?","&","/","="),$txt));
}
$c=encode('/?id=12&link=http://example.com/?id=123&p=param');
print($c."\n");
print(decode($c)."\n");
?>

Вывод:
*(Ch912)UsPZ,WCrH:*:jewqr}Z.MHq*;bP:12()H,AWNMm
/?id=12&link=http://example.com/?id=123&p=param
```

Начальное число `$x` можно менять на любое, главное что бы при расшифровке оно было таким же как при шифровании.